# need help in supporting multiple screens

Tags: android, size

I am creating an app that suppports multiple screen and I added for the drawable drawable with density qualifiers and size qulifier what I want to ask is:

1- what if I have small screen device with high density or medium what will the device choose which drawable will it choose the small one or the mdpi/hdpi one..?

2-how can i place a qualifier for example large qualifier drawable-large but that is specific for tablets which will be different then the large qualifier for other devices...

3-in my layout I have textview and an image, and i need to increase the size of my image as the device screen size increases same thing to the text... so what's the best solution what I did is that I placed in the layout-small a small image with a text of 14sp, for the large layout I placed a bigger image with 17sp text size... is this a good solution or will it cause some problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first make these folders in your `res` folder:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Then open and edit each and every layout  and then i your `ManifestFile` add this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
         android:normalScreens="true" 
         android:largeScreens="true"
         android:xlargeScreens="true"
         android:anyDensity="true"
         android:resizeable="true"/>
```

first check your `Manifest` file after creating folder if this code is there do nothing else `copy` and `paste` it...

Answer (score 0):

you can make the layout as like for multiple screen and images with different density

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density 48*48
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density   72*72
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density  96*96
```

Android manage itself according with dimension and density
Please read all those for multiple screen here
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

For different screen sizes the layout it's not coded in xml. It can be but the PRO's are doing it dinamically in the app. And for the resource like images you need 4 types atleast of 1 image for every screen like ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi.